# What is the reason for investigators not being eliminated when Yig awakens?

Tags: eldritch-horror, eldritch-horror-forsaken-lore

When Yig awakens, one of the rule items says:

> When an investigator is defeated or devoured, that player is **not eliminated**

What is the significance of this rule?  What is the non-eliminated player doing for the rest of the game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The player chooses a new investigator and keeps playing, which isn't the case for most ancient ones.